# How do you deploy Throng or Cluster with Angular Fullstack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, heroku

The documentation looks super simple for implementing Throng to create additional webworkers with Heroku. Having said that, it has left me with a couple of questions:

1) Do I also need to install Cluster; from what I read Throng is an abstraction of Cluster but I don't see Cluster included in the download. Did I miss something or is Throng ready to go out of the box?

2) Where I do put these few lines of code? Angular Fullstack has a server directory and an app.js file within the server directory.  This is my best bet but I could imagine that maybe it is better placed within the config directory or maybe even somewhere else.

3) In what order do I need to require Throng?  I understand that if things are out of order that can mess things up. If app.js is the right place to put var throng = require('throng').

The following link is my reference with the directions on Throng:
https://github.com/goodeggs/heroku-web-cluster

I put the following code in my app.js file beneath 'start server':

```
var throng = require('throng');
var WORKERS = process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || 1;
var start = function(){
  process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
    console.log('Worker exiting');
    process.exit();
  });
}
throng(start, {
  workers: 1,
  lifetime: Infinity,
});
```

When I do this I receive a quickly repeating error in my terminal when it is deployed locally:

```
Error: bind EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at cb (net.js:1178:33)
    at rr (cluster.js:592:14)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (cluster.js:563:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (cluster.js:692:8)
    at process.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at handleMessage (child_process.js:324:10)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:352:11)
Debugger listening on port 5889
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

        ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var express = require('express');
var cluster = require('cluster'); //no need to download anything
var os = require('os'); //no need to download anything

if(cluster.isMaster) {
   var numWorkers = os.cpus().length;
   console.log('Master cluster setting up ' + numWorkers + ' workers...');

   for(var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
       cluster.fork();
   }

   cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
       console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
   });

   cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
       console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
       console.log('Starting a new worker');
       cluster.fork();
   });
} else {
   var app = require('express')();
   var server = require('http').createServer(app);
   require('./config/express')(app);
   require('./routes')(app);

   // Start server
   server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
     console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
   });
}
```

Comment: This is not using throng ... is there no point for using throng I am trying to follow heroku's suggestion of throng...

Comment: @Lion789. Sorry I just saw this. It's been three months so I don't remember in detail anything about Throng other than to say that I decided not to use it and found that Cluster was simple enough that the abstraction Throng adds does not add value for my use case. From my POV I don't perceive a value add for Throng and I think Heroku's suggestion to being with this solution is misleading.

Comment: @rashadb Same here. The default implementation is so simple and explicit that throng abstraction was just adding a layer of complexity that is not needed